# OnClick Not Working While Looping To Other Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, react-component

*Sorry for function names*

I have a basic react app where it fetches the data i.e title and topic of blog and displays on the website

This is my List Component

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios'
import Card from './Card.js'

var cardComponent;
class getBlogs extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:8081/v1/todolist/todo1', {})
      .then( (response)=> {
        this.setState({retrieved : true})
        this.setState({data : response.data})
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });   
  }

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data : 'none' ,
      retrieved : 'true'
    }
  }

  onned = (event)=>{
    console.log('lof')
  }

  oh = ()=>{
    if(this.state.data !== 'none'){
       cardComponent = this.state.data.map((user , i)=>{
        var some = this.state.data;
        console.log(some[i].title)
        return <Card
          onClick={this.onned()}
          title={some[i].title}
          topic={some[i].topic}
        /> ;
      });
      return cardComponent;
    }
 }

 render(){
    if(this.state.retrieved === true){
      return (
        <div>{this.oh()}</div>
      );
    }
    else{
      return (
          <h1>Loading............................</h1>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default getBlogs;
```

It is fetching data and the oh function loops the data and sends to Card Component

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onDiv = (event)=>{
    console.log('hello')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <div  onClick ={this.onDiv()} style={{backgroundSize : 'cover'}} className=" form-control bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5">
              <div style={{marginLeft : '90px'}}>
                   <h1   style={{ textAlign : "center" , color : "red" , fontWeight : "bold"}} className="display-2">{this.props.title}</h1>
                   <h1   style={{ textAlign : "center" , color : "blue" , fontWeight : "bold"}} className="">{this.props.topic}</h1>
             </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <br/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Now what I want is if an user clicks one of the list of blog names it should redirect to other location but onClick of div is not working

While rendering itself the onClick gets executed

pls dont downvote i may get blocked

Comment: Try with `onClick ={() => this.onDiv()}`.

Comment: You are calling the function `onDiv` immediately. Don't call yourself, let it gets called by the `onClick` event, like `onClick ={this.onDiv}`

Comment: Thank you so so. so .................  much . The thing i did wrong was by putting those brackets . Can you explain briefly why it happens like that

Comment: when you do like in comment below `onClick={this.onDiv}` you bind a function `onDiv` to the `onClick` by reference, so if `onClick` has a reference to function, it can execute it. But when you pass it like `{this.onDiv()}` you immediately executes the function `onDiv` and pass the result of the function to the `onClick`, and of course you can't execute this as a function.

Comment: tysm everyone for the help

Comment: How to create a link to each one of the blog when it is clicked like for blog1 localhost:3000/get/blog1?? using  react router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `onClick ={this.onDiv}` instead of `onClick ={this.onDiv()}`. Instead of providing onClick with a callback you are calling the function there only

Comment: Yes but i have a question

Comment: How to create a link to each one of the blog when it is clicked like for blog1 localhost:3000/get/blog1?? using react router

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-string this should answer your question

Comment: I did not understand Can you pls pls pls explain